# ImportError: cannot import name 'global_sdk_config' from 'aws_xray_sdk'

Tags: python, aws-lambda, virtualenv, tox

Through Tox i am trying to run a unit test in my local. The test seems to fail, giving me the following error:

```
    from aws_xray_sdk import global_sdk_config
E   ImportError: cannot import name 'global_sdk_config' from 'aws_xray_sdk'
```

[image]

Looking at the package installed in virtaul environment created by tox, i see the following files in aws_sray_sdk :

[image]

Upon closer insepection, i see when i had created virtual environment myself (without tox) and run pip install aws-xray-sdk, i also see **sdk_config.py**
and **version.py** in package aws_sdk_xray as shown below:

[image]

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: In future, please do not post screenshots, but rather properly formatted/copied code. Also, in order to debug tox issues, it is always very helpful to have the output of `tox - rvv`  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the screenshot you show us tox running a Python 3.7 environment, and in the following screenshots you show us the site-packages of Python 3.6.

These do not match.

You need to make sure you inspect the correct tox environment.